# How to find limit of $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x^x$?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, exponentiation

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}^{}\sin{x}^{x}$. 
I tried this 
$ P =\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}(\sin{x})^x$
taking the natural log on both side we get
$\log_{e}P= \displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\log_{e}(\sin{x})^x$

$=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}x\ln(\sin{x})$

$=\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(\sin{x})}{1\over x}$

this is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

I think we should use L'Hospital's rule, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Well what is $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x$?

Comment: $\;x^x\;$ doesn't exist for $\;x<0\;$ and thus the wanted limit cannot exist. If you want to talk of the *right sided* then something can be done...perhaps.

Comment: If you mean $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin (x^x)$, then $\sin $ being continuous implies $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin x^x=\sin\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^x=\sin 1$. But I see that's not what you meant. $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin x^x$ is ambiguous.

Comment: @user31415 that is not the question

Comment: @ADG I know. I just pointed out that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}^{}\sin{x}^{x}$ is ambiguous, though later statements remove ambiguity.

Comment: @Timbuc your this example is wrong too.

Comment: @ADG I'm not sure what you're referring to: are you saying $\;x^x\;$ can be well defined as a *real* function in some **left**  (open) neighbourhood of zero? And what *example* of mine do you mean? Thank you.

Comment: @Timbuc yes it doesn't exist for <0, but the limit does.

Comment: @ADG That's impossible,, as **per definition**, for $\;\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)\;$ to have the slightest chance to exists it **must be true** that $\;f\;$ is defined in some (punctured) neighbourhood of $\;x_0\;$ , and that means *both-sided* neighbourhood. Also, in your answer, could you please explain what does $\;\log\sin x\;$ mean for $\;\sin x<0\;$ ?!

Comment: @Timbuc if you're not getting it see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/637299/67609)

Comment: @ADG I can't agree with that, and as far as I can see neither do several members here and, possibly, some authors here and there. Anyway, even if that convention is adopted, I think a little note explaining that would be in place.

Comment: @Timbuc well I can't say beyond that since I can't make you agree. I don't wish to argue.

Comment: @ADG In Hijab's "Int. to Calculus and Real Analysis", in  Thomas-Finney's " Calculus and Anal. Geom.", in Stewart's "Calculus, Early Trascendentals", etc. it is *explicitly* required the function to be defined in an open neighborhood of $\;x_0\;$ , *except perhaps at* that point itself, for the limit (without sides) to be existent. But I guess it all is a matter of definition...

Comment: re: I don't wish to argue. Opinions.

Answer (score 1):

For the right-hand side limit:

Suppose $0<x<\pi$.  Then:
$$x\ln(\sin x)=\frac x{\sin x}\cdot \sin x \ln(\sin x)$$
Now $\dfrac x{\sin x}\to 1$ as  $x\to 0$, and $\,u\ln u\to 0$ as $u\to 0_+$, so
$$x\ln(\sin x)\to 0\enspace\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to 0_+} (\sin x)^x = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x)^x=\lim_{x\to0}e^{x\ln(\sin x)}=\lim_{x\to0}e^{\displaystyle \frac{\ln(\sin x)}{1/x}}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to0}e^{\displaystyle \frac{\cot x}{-1/x^2}}=\lim_{x\to0}e^{\displaystyle -x\times\frac{x}{\tan x}}=e^{0\times1}=1$$

Comment: This can't be right as $\;x<0\implies (\sin x)^x\;$ isn't defined (for example, try with $\;x=-\frac1{20}\;$ ...)

Comment: @Timbuc well you're having it wrong, sorry but please read about limits again.

Comment: First, I think the function in the limit is *actually* $\;\sin\left(x^x\right)\;$ and *not* what you wrote, but whatever: How can a negative number be raised to a power $\;n/m\;$ , with $\;n\;$ an odd natural and $\;m\;$ and even one? Maybe I'm missing something here...

Comment: First, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1268489/revisions) and yes you are missing something [I'm just avoiding it ATM so that you find it yourself or else, if you need, I may tell you]

Comment: Sorry, I can't see your point, and I don't know what  ATM stands for. And please be kind to me and tell me **exactly** what it is I'm missing instead of repeating over and over that I'm missing something. Thanks.

Comment: @Timbuc nevermind, I never intended to do that. I just told you to see original post by the OP and I've linked you to [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/637299/67609) where it is explained that lim can exist for undefined functions on one side.