# Prove that $\sqrt{x}$ continuous at 0

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

please check my proof

we have

$|x-0|<\delta \rightarrow |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{0}|<\epsilon $

$\rightarrow \sqrt{x}<\epsilon $

$\rightarrow x<\epsilon ^{2}$

choose $\delta=\epsilon ^{2}$

therefore 
$|x-0|<\delta \rightarrow |\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{0}|<\sqrt{\epsilon ^{2}}=\epsilon $

Then it is continuous at $ 0 $

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1914931/is-sqrt-x-continuous-at-0-because-it-is-not-defined-to-the-left-of-0

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488942/is-sqrtx-continuous-at-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: And also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637280/limit-of-sqrt-x-as-x-approaches-0?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe interesting to prove something stronger ...

For all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such $0\le x\le y$ :

$$\sqrt y\le\sqrt{y-x}+\sqrt x$$

(obvious by comparing the squares)

So, for all $(x,y)\in[0,+\infty)^2$ :

$$|\sqrt y-\sqrt x|\le\sqrt{|y-x|}$$

Given $\epsilon>0$, the condition $|y-x|\le\epsilon^2$ implies $|\sqrt y-\sqrt x|\le\epsilon$.

This proves that $t\mapsto\sqrt t$ is uniformly continuous, hence continuous, hence continuous at 0.

Comment: It's just asked proof for continuous at a point but that thank for example for uniformly continuous How about my proof  Is it correct?

Comment: @Lingnoi401: Your reasoning is correct, but IMHO badly written. You should emphasize that it is a proof by sufficient condition (and replace "we have" at the top by "we would like to show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that ..."). And also you should use "\implies" to get $\implies$ (instead of $\rightarrow$).

Comment: thank you for comment  ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

Your use of $\leftrightarrow$ is awful !

Let $ \epsilon >0$. Put $\delta =\epsilon^2$. If $0 \le x < \delta$ then $0 \le\sqrt{x}< \epsilon$