# For the following exercise use the formal definition to directly prove the f'(a) exists

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

The definition in the book is: A real function f is said to be differentiable at a point $a \in \mathbb{R}$ if and only if f is defined on some open interval $I$ containing a and $$f'(a):=\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

The function given is $$f(x) = \sqrt{x}, a\gt 0$$

$f'(a) = lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a}}{h}$

I just don't know how to simplify from here. Super embarrassing.

Comment: Multiply and divide by the sum of the square roots.

Comment: Do you need to use the formal definition for the limit $L$ of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $c$:
$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$$
if $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\delta>0\ \text{such that}\ 0<|x-c|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: no the definition is stated as above

Comment: Conjugate. That is all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just multiply the expression by $1=\frac{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}$ to see that your differential quotient becomes $\frac{x+h-x}{h(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}\to\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}=f'(a)$.

Comment: And why is $\lim_{h\to 0}\sqrt{a+h}=\sqrt{a}$?

Comment: Use the method given in the answer of this other question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190573/prove-that-sqrtx-continuous-at-0

Answer (score 0):

Write your term as $$\frac{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a}}{h}=\frac{a+h-a}{h(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a})}$$