# When do i check the sides of a limit in order to find a limit?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

When do i need to check the sides to see if the limit exists?
Do i do this only on multi type functions?
Thanks!

Comment: "Check the sides?"  Can you give an example fo what you mean?  Also, what is a "multi type function?"

Comment: By checking the sides i mean finding the limit of x->x0 from left or right of x0.An example of a multi type function is this: f (x)=x if x>0 or f (x)=-x if x <-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the definitions of the limit is that if
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to a^-} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x\to a^+} f(x)$$
then
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)$$

That is, the limit only exists if the left and right sided limits are the same.  If, for example, you have reason to believe that a function (in your case, a piecewise function) is discontinuous at $x=a$, then you can try to find the left and right sided limits to see if the limit exists.

Comment: This only defines the limit over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is only “half true” and can lead to misconceptions; see this question, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637280/limit-of-sqrt-x-as-x-approaches-0