# Why is $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x = 1$?

Tags: limits, soft-question, analytic-geometry

I was always taught by my professors when I was doing Calculus that we only have limit (two-sided) of a function if the function itself is approachable from the left and the right. (Note that, here I'm talking about the limit in **Real** set).

Geometrically, I still can't process why

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x = 1,$$

in spite of the fact that algebraically we can show that the limit above is approaching $1$ from the left by rewriting the limit as

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} e^{\ln{\left(x^x\right)}}$$

and reducing it with L'hôpital's rule we get:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} e^{-x} = 1.$$

However, I graphed the function on *Geogebra* and we also know that there are **some** value for $x<0$ in $\Bbb R$ (**not all values**) that make $y$ isn't available in the real set. So, why is the function said to be approachable from the left (geometrically)? We know if $x<0$ and when $y$ isn't available in $\Bbb R$, $y\in \Bbb C$, right? Is it because the continuity of the left part of the value of the limit of the function doesn't matter or what?

P.S. Here, I also provide what Wolfram Alpha says about the limit:

[image]

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x =1$ but how do you even define $x^x$ for negative $x$?  Especially negative irrational $x$?

Comment: @Henry I'm sorry I'm lost. I mean, we still have the possibility $y$ is available in $\Bbb R$ for example $x=-1$

Comment: "... I still can't process why..." Why do you think $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x = 1$? This identity is not even false. Where is this from?

Comment: What do you think $x^x$ is when $x=-\frac12$?  When $x=-\frac13$? When $x=-\frac1\pi$?  You need it defined for all $x$ near $0$ to be able to take a limit

Comment: @LouisPan As I said before that we only have limit (two-sided)... Most people believe that the value of the two-sided limit is one (in my Maths group). Actually, I also want to confirm this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. You said "I still can't process why $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x = 1$"; and I asked *where* you saw this. This is a "wrong" identity. Or you thought you should have $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x = 1$ and hence the question?

Comment: @Henry Still lost sorry. Are you saying the limit isn't 1. Or the left-sided limit doesn't exist?

Comment: limit is just approaching the value from all directions possible, if you can only approach it from one direction then that's the direction that matters for the limit.
Also you know that $x^x$ for $x < 0$ requires mapping to $\mathbb{C}$ yet you still tried to plot it on Geogebra ...?

Comment: @okzoomer Sorry I didn't explain it in detail. But I'm talking about the value in Real set.

Comment: I am saying the limit naturally does not exist using real numbers as $x^x$ is undefined for most negative non-integers, but a suitable treatment might.  One approach (which could cause other problems) might be to look at $|x|^{-|x|} e^{-i \pi x}$ when $x$ is negative and see its limit goes to $1$ as $x \to 0^-$.  This requires complex numbers.

Comment: then for $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined over $(a, b)$ you only look at one-sided limit if you approach $a$ or $b$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/637280/limit-of-sqrt-x-as-x-approaches-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the world of *real* analysis, the function $f(x)=x^x$ is defined only for positive real numbers. Its domain is $(0,\infty)$. So it does not make sense to write $\lim_{x \to 0^-} x^x$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ does not exist<sup>$\dagger$</sup>. On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{x\ln x}=1
$$
where we use the *definition* $x^x:=e^{x\ln(x)}$ for $x>0$.

In *complex* analysis, one could extend the function for negative values of $x$ (or even complex values in general). What one has then is
$$
x^x=e^{x\text{Ln}(x)},\quad x<0
$$
where $\text{Ln}$ takes a branch that contains the negative x-axis.

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup> Sometimes, people write $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a;x\in S}f(x)$ where $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is the domain of $f$ and $a$ is an accumulation point of $S$. When the context is clear, one may write $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$, omitting $x\in S$. In the above example, if one writes $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$, one really means $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x^x=1$.

Comment: That's **exactly** the answer I want to know! Thanks a bunch! Does that mean when people forget to write the positive they can't say the two-sided limit exists?

Comment: @user516076: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @user516076 you should read the edit

Comment: @okzoomer I did. Thanks.